# How to setup a Azure VPN on the client side for internet access purposes (Google behind GFW)?

Tags: azure, vpn, ppp, azure-vpn

I'm trying to setup a VPN for internet access purposes (I'm in china behind the the great firewall) but I'm not an networking expert.

Someone out of China who has an Azure subscription created a package for allowing me to connect to that VPN with the related pfx certificate and so far everything, seems to be good, the connection can be achieved with a server located in Europe, the VPN server is 172.16.0.1 the VPN Client is within a range 172.16.0.X.

About the package creation he followed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/06/05/configure-a-point-to-site-vpn-connection-to-an-azure-vnet.aspx

However, when I'm connected to the VPN I do not have any way to access to Google, I'm struggling to affirm whether it is a configuration on my side or just the GFW that is messing up. I'm struggling about my configuration cause it seems that there is no real connection with that newly defined connection:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can ping the related server server when I'm connected to the VPN but there is no way to get access to google.com, however the DNS resolution name lookup seems to work at least.

Being connected to the VPN the lookup operation gives a me an appropriate result

[image]

[image]

and while I'm not connected to the almighty VPN:

[image]

[image]

I can still ping the VPN server when connected and vice versa when I'm not, which is quite normal:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to check and settle that the internet access is passing through the VPN? I'm also thinking whether this can result from a routing issue, but when checking `route print` I obtain the following list, but I don't really see anything wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Azure VPN Gateway drops any packets destined for the internet. It is not supported.